# Eclipse 2021-03 and my 'ctrl + /' is not working

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse 2021-03 and my 'ctrl + /' is not working (should comment out the line). I have followed the advice in this forum:

- Closed and reopened the project
- closed all open tabs and re opened
- Restored defaults
- Removed the .recommenders file in the Eclipse Workspace and restart the Eclipse
- Restart in the File menu
- Disabled the welcome screen

Comment: In which editor and for which file?

Comment: Open up the Preferences dialog, then the "Keys" tab. Use the filter and sort facilities to find the function and binding in question. If you see something unexpected, that will be a clue.

Comment: Hi Howlger, n general editor for .js file.

Comment: Hi David, This shows Commend: Toggle Comment, Binding: Ctrl+/, When: Editing JavaScript Source, Category: Source. I think it must be something to do with the editor. I tried to use another editor; however, there is no JavaScript edit available when I try "Open With", "Other".

Comment: As a work around I am using the Java editor. There seems to be no m ore support for JavaScript in Eclipse 2021-03. Would love to know how to install a proper JavaScript editor. I tried installing JavaScript Development Tools; however, the JavaScript editor still did not show in the option (I did restart Eclipse).

Comment: In Eclipse 2021-03 .js files are by default mistakenly opened in the plain text editor without JavaScript support instead of in the Generic Text Editor with JavaScript support (assuming [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) is part of your Eclipse or installed). I contributed a patch for this and it's now fixed in Eclipse 2021-06 which was released two days ago. The JavaScript Development Tools does not provide a stand-alone JavaScript editor anymore.

Comment: @howlger I used "Open With" then "Generic Text Editor" and that editor does not work with Ctrl+/. So, I found "Wild Web Developer" in the Eclipse Market Place it was already installed, so I did an update. I used "Open With" then "Generic Text Editor" and that editor does not work with Ctrl+/. So I then did a software update. I used "Open With" then "Generic Text Editor" and that editor does not work with Ctrl+/. So, do I need to download and set up Eclipse again after only just doing this last week! By the way, I greatly appreciate your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have had the same issue with Eclipse 202212 (new install)

Javascript,  Generic Text Editor, Wild Web Developer   Ctrl + /  does not Toggle Comments.

I got it to work by copying the key binding 'Toggle Line Comment' (not Toggle Comment) which is bound to 'Ctrl+Shift+C' When 'Editing Text' and creating a new entry with the binding to 'Ctrl+/', note: the Category is 'TM43 Language Configuration'